# UITableViewCell containing UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know this has been asked plenty of times. But how do I place a `UITextView` inside a `UITableViewCell` wherein, I need to satify the following:

1. `UITextView` is not editable.
2. `UITableView` should scroll when I touch on the `UITextView` to scroll.
3. `UITextView` should be interactable, in the sense, if I have a link in it, I should be able to open it in Safari.
4. Touching on the `UITextView` should also call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

1,2 and 4 are possible if I do `[cell.textView setUserInteraction:NO]`

But in that case, 3 doesn't work. How do I get all these conditions to satisfy?

Thanks.

Comment: this question is very useful. do not know why negative votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) in the past and it worked really well! This is a UILabel that has attributed text detection and delegate methods to handle the interaction with this text. Since it acts like a UILabel, it ends up satisfying your points too.

1. It is not editable.
2. It is not scrollable.
3. You are able to interact with it (and customize what happens when an attributed text is selected)
4. Touches should be forwarded down to the cell itself, triggering `didSelectCellAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 0):

In-spite of using this code:-

```
//[cell.textView setUserInteraction:NO]
```

Use this :-

```
[cell.textView setEditable:NO];
```

Comment: if I set userInteraction to NO, I wont be able to click the links. If I set it to YES, I wont be able to scroll the tableView if I touch on top of the textView. The textView has been set to not editable

Answer (score 0):

In this case better go with `UIScrollview` and add UILabel on it.

And use

> interactive rich text UILabel
>
> Go though this [link](http://locassa.com/interactive-rich-text-uilabel/)
>   And Fancy [UILabel](http://furbo.org/2008/10/07/fancy-uilabels/)

Answer (score 0):

One way you are disabling the interaction and other way you are trying to make it touchable ...Please be clear with your requirement .. to mean while you can try UILable or UIButton..try this .. https://github.com/facebook/three20

Answer (score 0):

Assign a tag value equal to the cell number (or something else that is unique and helps you to map the textview to the cell)

Disable the textview edit and scroll. This would solve 1 & 2. Enable user interaction of the text view, 3 is solved. Add a gesture recogniser to the text view and in that check the text view tag and call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and also return YES from that function so as to allow the textview to receive that touch and perform the required action (opening the link etc).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It s working fine.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];


    UITextView *desclbl = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 15, 100, 50)];

    desclbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    desclbl.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    desclbl.editable = NO;

    desclbl.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];

    desclbl.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;

    desclbl.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:desclbl];

    desclbl.tag = 25;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}

UITextView *lblDesc = (UITextView*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:25];

lblDesc.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"];

return cell;
```

}